# p:datatable component is not sorting, only when I filter it before

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Im trying to present my data from a mysql Database in a Datatable, and its all working, now i was trying to include a filter and sorting functionality, but when I test it and press the sorting arrows, nothing happens, only when I filter the datatable first, and then everything works fine.

I tried it with the primeface Attributes filterBy and sortBy, and because of the existing functionality I think it has something to do with a update-Problem

```html
<p:dataTable id="test3" scrollable="true" scrollHeight="150"  var="Foo" value="#{Foo.bar}">
    
       <p:column headerText="#{msg['default-description-key']}" 
       sortBy="#{Foo.keyString}" 
       filterBy="#{Foo.keyString}">
                                            
           <p:outputLabel  value="#{Foo.keyString}" 
           style="float:center"/>     
                          
       </p:column>                                       
       <p:column headerText="#{msg['default-description-count']}" 
       sortBy="#{Foo.count}" filterBy="#{Foo.count}">
                                            
           <p:outputLabel value="#{Foo.count}" 
           style="float:center"/>
                                        
       </p:column>                                        
       <p:column headerText="#{msg['default-description-register.key']}">
                                            
           <p:commandLink value="#{msg['default-description- 
           register.key.link']}" action="#{Foo.bar(Foo.keyString)}"/>
                                        
       </p:column>
                                   
</p:dataTable>
```

I want to be able to sort the datatable without the need of filtering it before

Answer (score 0):

- Create a separate list in your bean (don't forget getter and setter) and link it to the attribute filteredValue in the p:dataTable component
- Place the table inside h:form
- Use h:outputText instead of p:outputLabel